# Gitbash - Vs code link

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

when i want to use gitbash with the terminal of vs code, I've got an error.

> "Impossible ti write in parametre user. please open file of parametre
> user to correct errors."

When I click on "parametre", I open a file "`settings.json`"
In this file, the error is Expected comma jsonc(514)
On the 7 line, I've got the "editor.rulers"

[git terminal problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbwsF.png)

Someone could help me please?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a comma on line 6.